# ドキュメントルートを変更したら403になった

Tags: centos, apache

Apacheでドキュメントルートの場所を変更しました。
/home/ユーザネーム/www/public

一応chmodでpublicを777に変更したんですが、403のエラーがでます。
これってもしかして、publicまでのディレクトリすべてを777にしないといけないのですか？

他に方法あれば教えてください。

Comment: ドキュメントルートにindexファイルはありますか？なければindex.htmlを適当に作って置いてみてください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CentOS 7.3 の Apache 2.4.6 で検証しました。

上記環境で Apache の DocumentRoot を /home 配下に変更した場合の権限問題を解決する最も簡単な方法は以下の通りです。

```
setenforce 0
chmod 755 /home/username
```

ユーザーのホームディレクトリに権限を与えないと駄目なようです。 [*](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451922/apache-access-denied-because-search-permissions-are-missing/504525#comment965107_504525)

CentOS 7 では SELinux がデフォルトで有効になっているので、パーミッションの変更以外に SELinux の対応も必要です。
`setenforce 0` は再起動すると戻るので、コンテキストを変更するか、常時無効にしたい場合は /etc/selinux/config で `SELINUX=disabled` を指定する必要があります。

Comment: setenforce 0 は、このまま実行してから、chmod 755 /home/usernameを実行すればいいんですよね？

Comment: 変更して表示もできました。ありがとうございました。